Authentication failed while connecting to docker-compose mongodb via springboot application
docker-compose.yml
version: '4'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:7.0.5
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: product-service
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

application.properties
spring.application.name=product-service
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/product-service?authSource=admin

While I debug my code I get the expected result but just couldn't connect to docker mongodb.
When I tried to execute the application I get
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}


To resolve the authentication issue, you need to set up a MongoDB initialization script to create a user with the necessary roles.
the file looks like this :
db.createUser(
        {
            user: "root",
            pwd: "password",
            roles: [
                {
                    role: "readWrite",
                    db: "product-service"
                }
            ]
        }
);

then you need to Modify your docker-compose.yml file to mount the script into the MongoDB container.
You should take a look here : How to create a DB for MongoDB container on start up?
